# schema validation when supporting oracle and mssql

Tags: hibernate

I'm not expert on neither db, but IIUC mssql varchar2 does not support unicode characters, while oracle varchar2 theoretically can, based on configuration. I need to be able store unicode characters. So in mssql I can use nvarchar2, and annotate field with `@Nationalized`. Validation is fine. But in oracle I don't need to do that, from db point of view, and I will no justify schema change. And if I run the code with `@Nationalized` against oracle, it will indeed fail with:

```
found [varchar2 (Types#VARCHAR)], but expecting [nvarchar2(255) (Types#NVARCHAR)]
```

I understand the message, but it is possible to somehow finetune it, so that it is OK with oracle varchar2, which can hold unicode characters? Or generally speaking, is there some other db-type/db-configuration + hibernate configuration, so that I can have unicode in db and validation for both dbs?

Comment: Check this might help: https://gullele.com/adding-unicode-character-to-mysql-from-java-hibernate/

Comment: thanks for quick reply, sadly it does not work. What article recommends seems to somehow alter the session, which is not sufficient, as I need to make this work for whoever connects. I tried it anyways, and it does not work. ;; using nvarchar and nationalized does work, but this makes entities incompatible with oracle using varchar2.